# Access denied due to firewall policy violation

Tags: java, html, security, web-applications, vpn

I have run into a very strange situation that I have never seen before and I could not find any relevant issues on the web into resolving my problem. The situation is the following:

When a user connected using a VPN connection to the local office network and tries to access a web application (apache tomcat / servlets / mySql) and on very specific requests the users receive an error:

```
Your access is

denied

Access denied due to firewall policy violation

Your issue ID for support is: 5e81fac2-1-1ae9967f-c0000000
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

This error comes when a user presses a save button which performs a jQuery ajax request to the server. The error only appears so far when I have the word "find" in the ckEditor as shown above(`<div>any-text find any-text</div>`). When the find word is replaced everything works ok. Looking in the encoded message that is transferred it looks something like this:

Not Working:
`clName=A+S+LTD&contactPerson=S+Ei&contactEmail=&contactPhone=002&problem=%3Cdiv%3Efind%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A&subject=Support............`

Working:
`clName=A+S+LTD&contactPerson=S+Ei&contactEmail=&contactPhone=002&problem=%3Cdiv%3Eind%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A&subject=Support............`

`clName=A+S+LTD&contactPerson=S+Ei&contactEmail=&contactPhone=002&problem=%3Cdiv%3Efxnd%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A&subject=Support............`

`clName=A+S+LTD&contactPerson=S+Ei&contactEmail=&contactPhone=002&problem=find&subject=Support............`

I have this issue for two users working remotely using a VPN connection (Checkpoint end point security). On my local network when everyone else is connected the same request works fine.

Does anyone have ANY clue where this message comes from or how can it be resolved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is almost certainly some overly clever WAF rule applied at your firewall; you need to contact the netadmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that @chrylis-on-strike was right. The problem indeed came from the Checkpoint firewall.

It seems that the word 'find' was detected as a 'command injection' and was blocked.

[image]

The solution was to add a rule on the firewall to just detect and not block this kind of requests coming from the VPN connected clients.